# Bind DataTemplate item to DataGrid`s SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm having problem with binding `TextBox` text which is inside `DataTemplate` tag.

There is `ItemsControl` which is bound to `ObservableCollection<ControlModel> ControlsCollection`. There it is code (with `DataGrid` included:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxDataTemplate">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ControlName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,0,0,0" Width="616" Height="35" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding ControlValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControlsCollection}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ControlTemplateSelector}"/>

<DataGrid Margin="25,100,25,50" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductSpecificationView}"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCell}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="col1" Binding="{Binding Index,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   />

        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="col2" Binding="{Binding IndexName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   />

        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="col3" Binding="{Binding TechnologyStructure,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   />

        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="col4" Binding="{Binding TechVariants,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    />

        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="col5" Binding="{Binding TechTwoVariants,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    />

   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

... and ControlModel:

```
public class ControlModel : ViewModel
{
    private string controlName;

    public string ControlName
    {
        get { return controlName; }
        set
        {
            controlName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ControlName");
        }
    }

    private string controlValue;

    public string ControlValue
    {
        get { return controlValue; }
        set
        {
            controlValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ControlValue");
        }
    }
    public string ControlType { get; set; }

    public ControlModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Finally this is how I'm populating my `ControlsCollection`:

```
public void GetControlsCollection()
    {
        using (var conn = Connection.Connect())
        {
            string query = "select c.control_name, " +
                           "ct.control_type_name,c.control_property_name from Controls c " +
                           "inner join ControlsType ct on k.kontrolka_typ_id = tk.kontrolka_typ_id ";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                { 
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string controlValue = "";
                        string controlProp = reader[2].ToString();

                        if (SelectedProduct != null)
                        {
                            controlValue = SelectedProduct.GetType().GetProperty(controlProp).GetValue(SelectedProduct, null).ToString();
                        }

                        ControlsCollection.Add(new ControlModel()
                        {
                            ControlName = reader[0].ToString(),
                            ControlType = reader[1].ToString(),
                            ControlValue = controlValue
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't bind...

```
 <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,0,0,0" Width="616" Height="35" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding ControlValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

properly. How to bind this `TextBox` to get `SelectedProduct` property (of course with selection change) ? Every `SelectedProduct` property has
`OnPropertyChanged()` trigger.

Comment: So, inside the ItemsControl you want to bind the TextBox's Text to the main view model's `SelectedProduct` property *instead* of binding to an item's `ControlValue`?

Comment: @Clemens Something like that. TextBox's Text should be bound to `ControlValue`. The real question is. How to pass value from `SelectedProduct` to the `ControlValue` every time I change selection ?

Comment: Well, by writing code. WPF doesn't provide a built-in solution for that task.

Comment: @Clemens and I'm so close to it. Using `controlValue = SelectedProduct.GetType().GetProperty(controlProp).GetValue(SelectedProduct, null).ToString();` sets value at the beginning only. Can you tell me how to provide "update" to it ?

Comment: There certainly is a SelectedProduct property setter. Update the ControlValue of an associated ControlModel object there.